# How to aggregate a column in a pandas dataframe by using other columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, aggregate, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataframe which contains duplicate records with columns v,w,x,y,z.

```
V   W    X   Y   Z
a   US   1   0   88
a   US   0   1   88
a   US   2   0   88
a   RUS  1   2   23
b   IND  2   0   12
b   IND  1   3   12
b   RSA  0   1   5
c   BAN  5   6   10
```

I want to remove duplicates from V,W,Z columns by aggregating the X,Y columns.This would lead to:

```
V   W    X    Y  Z
a   US   3    1  88   
a   RUS  1    2  23
b   IND  3    3  12
b   RSA  0    1  5
c   BAN  5    6  10
```

I cannot figure out how to so this in python , please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = df = df.groupby(['V','W','Z'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()

print(df)
   V    W   Z  X  Y
0  a   US  88  3  1
1  a  RUS  23  1  2
2  b  IND  12  3  3
3  b  RSA   5  0  1
4  c  BAN  10  5  6
```